# for loop iteration and netmiko just doing the first device

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, network-programming, netmiko

I have been doing some network automation, now I am working with for lops to be able to do not only one at time, so when I ran the code below I see the first router it is successful but the second one has the error netmiko.ssh_exception.NetmikoTimeoutException: Timed-out reading channel, data not available.

So I am testing with 3 routers, the first goes well but the second one never works.

```
from netmiko import Netmiko
from getpass import getpass
import re

router1 = {
    "host": "10.0.0.248",
    "username": "cisco",
    "password": "cisco",
    "device_type": "cisco_ios",
}

router2 = {
    "host": "10.0.0.247",
    "username": "cisco",
    "password": "cisco",
    "device_type": "cisco_ios",
}

router3 = {
    "host": "10.0.0.246",
    "username": "cisco",
    "password": "cisco",
    "device_type": "cisco_ios",
}

routers = [router1, router2, router3]

interface_shut = list()

for router in routers:
    net_connect = Netmiko(**router)
    print(net_connect.find_prompt())
    output = net_connect.send_command("show ip int br")
    print(output)
    find_interfaces = re.findall("GigabitEthernet\d.\d", output)
    print(find_interfaces)
    for int in find_interfaces:
        interface_shut.append("Interface " + int)
        interface_shut.append("no shut")
        output2 = net_connect.send_config_set(interface_shut)
        print(output2)
        interface_shut = list() # I am doing this so the list doesnt have to have more than 3 items for each device
        print(interface_shut)
    net_connect.disconnect()
```

Comment: what is the error message that you are getting please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was my bad. The code is working fine. I just forgot to add the priv 15 in the other 2 routers.